# Redirecting with AngularJS/OIDC not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, thinktecture-ident-server

I have some SPA code that's using Manfred Steyer's OIDC client and Identity Server as the Token Service it works great in Chrome & Firefox. But for some reason or another it's not working in IE 11. I get this error

```
Unhandled exception at line 3855, column 3 in 
http://localhost:82/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js

"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
 H/<@http://localhost:82/js/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
 $digest@http://localhost:82/js/angular/angular.min.js:139:243
 $apply@http://localhost:82/js/angular/angular.min.js:141:339
 f/q<@http://localhost:82/js/angular/angular.min.js:154:284
 e@http://localhost:82/js/angular/angular.min.js:45:256
 Zf/k.defer/c<@http://localhost:82/js/angular/angular.min.js:48:158

 This is code:

jQuery.readyException = function( error ) {
   window.setTimeout( function() {
    throw error;
} );
};
```

I'm using Angular UI Router which has the hashcode to split the routes. Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: does it happen on all the routes in the application ? do you have any custom code for route handling?

Comment: No just routes that are secured. I checked local storage for the tokens and it seems it's not being stored. So I'm guessing in the redirect that code isn't running.